# Counting the number of checked items inside of a Repeater ASP .NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

my javascript/ jquery is rusty. How would i go about getting the count of checked items inside of a repeater from ASP .NET web forms, if it helps i can slap a div around it. Could someone show me some example code please? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Asp repeater :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="YourRepeaterID" runat="server" >
</asp:Repeater>
```

Count check box inside a repeater:

```
 var count = 0;
 count = $('#' + '<%= YourRepeaterID.ClientID %>').find('input:checked').length;
```

***Note : your jquery code must be inside document.ready and don't forget to include jquery library.***